# How to iterate over folders in Python

Tags: python

Have repository folder in which I have 100 folders of images. I want to iterate over each folder and then do the same over images inside these folders.

for example : repository --> folder1 --> folder1_images ,folder2 --> folder2_images ,folder3 --> folder3_images

May someone know elegante way of doing it?

P.S my OS is MacOS (have .DS_Store files of metadata inside)

Answer (score 3):

You can do use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to visit every subdirectory, recursively.  Here's a general starting point:

```
import os
parent_dir = '/home/example/folder/'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(parent_dir):
    for file in files:
        print os.path.join(subdir, file)
```

Instead of `print`, you can do whatever you want, such as checking that the file type is image or not, as required here.

Comment: Yeah, this great, but I'm stucked with moving up one folder from the list of folders that I have. That's the problem I have dirs = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3']. How to move up inside it?

Comment: I dont get it. can you please expalin this "problem I have dirs = ['folder1', 'folder2', 'folder3']. How to move up inside it?"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at os.walk which is meant exactly to loop through sub-directories and the files in them.

More info at : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: isn't it just `os.walk` ?

Answer (score 1):

Everyone has covered how to iterate through directories **recursively**, but if you don't need to go through all directories recursively, and you just want to iterate over the subdirectories in the current folder, you could do something like this:

```py
dirs = list(filter(lambda d: os.path.isdir(d), os.listdir(".")))
```

Annoyingly, the [listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) function doesn't only list directories, it also lists files as well, so you have to apply the `os.path.isdir()` function to conditionally 'extract' the elements from the list only if they're a directory and not a file.

(Tested with Python 3.10.6)